# How to plot dates on a timeline in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a column of dates, eg.

```
2017-01-20
2017-01-25
2017-01-27
2017-01-30
2017-02-03
...
2018-12-20
```

I would like to create a plot where the x-axis is a contiguous range of dates from start to end (ie. 2017-01-20 to 2018-12-20). The y-axis would be a count of how many events happened on that day.

In my case, the event will occur either 0 or 1 times on each day. The data represents the days of the year on which I exercised, and I want to visualize it.

How can I plot this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that requires creating the contiguous date range (the x-axis values) in a separate column.

The high-level idea is to create a column with every date from start to end, then create a column that indicates whether each date is within the list of days on which the event occurred.

- Insert the list of dates on which the event happened into column A
- Highlight Columns A and B, and select **Format > Number > Date** from the menu
- Add the start date, and the day after the start date in the first two rows of column B
- Select the first two rows of column B, and then drag the little blue dot in the right corner of the selection down to automatically create a date series.
- Keep dragging down until the desired end date is reached

*Note: the date format in these examples is M/DD/YYYY*
[image]

- In the first row of column C, enter `=COUNTIF(A:A, "="&$B1)` and press Enter. Then select the first row of column C, and fill down by double clicking the little blue dot in the right corner of the selection.

[image: fill formula]

- Select columns B and C, and then select Insert > Chart from the menu
- Change the **Chart type** to **Column chart**
- Double click the chart, and select **Customize > Gridlines**, select **Apply to Vertical axis**, and set **Major gridline count** to **2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- populate column **A** with dates
- populate column **B** with logic `=IF(C1="",0,1)`
- populate column **C** wit events
- select dataset of **A** and **B** columns
- go to **Insert** > **Chart**
- then double click the chart and edit **gridlines** of **vertical axis** to **major gridline count: 2**

[image]